# How to work around problem with Python smtpd?

Tags: python-3.x, smtpd

I want to make a small SMTP server for testing, using Python, so I was trying the server example code

https://pymotw.com/2/smtpd/

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
    print 'Receiving message from:', peer
    print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
    print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
    print 'Message length        :', len(data)
    return

server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 1025), None)

asyncore.loop()
```

Together with the example client code on that same page:

```
import smtplib
import email.utils
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Create the message
msg = MIMEText('This is the body of the message.')
msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Recipient', 'recipient@example.com'))
msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Author', 'author@example.com'))
msg['Subject'] = 'Simple test message'

server = smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1', 1025)
server.set_debuglevel(True) # show communication with the server
try:
    server.sendmail('author@example.com', ['recipient@example.com'], msg.as_string())
finally:
    server.quit()
```

However, when I try to run the client, I am getting the following on the server side:

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <smtpd.SMTPChannel connected 127.0.0.1:38634 at 0x7fe28a901490> (<class 'TypeError'>:process_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mail_options' [/root/Python-3.8.1/Lib/asyncore.py|read|83] [/root/Python-3.8.1/Lib/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|420] [/root/Python-3.8.1/Lib/asynchat.py|handle_read|171] [/root/Python-3.8.1/Lib/smtpd.py|found_terminator|386])
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mysmtpd.py", line 18, in <module>
asyncore.loop()
  File "/root/Python-3.8.1/Lib/asyncore.py", line 203, in loop
poll_fun(timeout, map)
  File "/root/Python-3.8.1/Lib/asyncore.py", line 144, in poll
r, w, e = select.select(r, w, e, timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Then I found this Issue page:

https://bugs.python.org/issue35837

and I think that that is the problem I've been running into.

That issue hasn't been fixed yet, so I was wondering if, meantime, is there something that I can modify in the example client code that would get around the problem that is described in that issue?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Add an `mail_options=None` in your `process_message()` function.

Comment: how so? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just for reference, do the same with the rcpt_options argument.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html?highlight=process_message#smtpd.SMTPServer.process_message

Comment: Consider adding this as a comment or add here some details from that link.

Answer (score -1):

The error seems to appear
in the line with `def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):`.
You can replace it with `def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data,**my_krargs):`